# Edges Overlapping Nodes Simple Tikz Picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have looked through a variety of sources and they all seem to address this issue but with a slight variation on how the picture itself is drawn, making their solution not applicable to me. I am very new to LaTeX and even newer to Tikz, and thus do not know entirely what I am doing but my issue is that there are edges in my graph, and they seem to be overlapping the nodes. A picture is attached. I do not want this happening, and do not seem to find a single solution. Thank you very much for your time.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{% This is the style settings for nodes
    dep/.style={rectangle,minimum size=1cm,fill=orange!20,draw=orange,
                general shadow={fill=gray!60,shadow xshift=1pt,shadow yshift=-1pt}},
    cli/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum size=0.5cm,fill=white},
    spl/.style={cli,append after command={
                  node[circle,draw,dotted,
                       minimum size=1.5cm] at (\tikzlastnode.center) {}}},
    c1/.style={-stealth,black!80!black},
    v2/.style={-stealth,very thick,yellow!65!black},
    v4/.style={-stealth,very thick,purple!70!black}}
\node[cli] (0) at (5,3) {1*+2*+3*};
\node[cli] (1) at (9,2) {1*+1*+3*};
\node[cli] (2) at (3,2) {1*+2*+2*};
\node[cli] (3) at (1,2) {2*+3*};
\node[cli] (4) at (0,1) {2*+2*};

\node[cli] (5) at (4.7,0.5) {1*+3*};
\node[cli] (6) at (6.7,0.5) {1*+1*+2*};
\node[cli] (7) at (2,-0.5) {3*};
\node[cli] (8) at (3.5,-0.5) {1*+2*};

\node[cli] (9) at (1,-1.2) {2*};
\node[cli] (10) at (9,-0.5) {1*+1*+1*};
\node[cli] (13) at (6.5,-1.5) {1*+1*};

\node[cli] (11) at (5,-2.2) {1*};
\node[cli] (12) at (5,-3.2) {0*};
\draw[c1] (5) -- (8);

\draw[c1] (0) -- (1);
\draw[c1] (0) -- (2);
\draw[c1] (0) -- (3);
\draw[c1] (2) -- (4);
\draw[c1] (3) -- (4);
\draw[c1] (2) -- (6);
\draw[c1] (3) -- (6);
\draw[c1] (1) -- (5);
\draw[c1] (1) -- (6);
\draw[c1] (0) -- (8);
\draw[c1] (5) -- (7);
\draw[c1] (6) -- (8);
\draw[c1] (3) -- (7);
\draw[c1] (2) -- (8);

\draw[c1] (4) -- (8);
\draw[c1] (4) -- (9);
\draw[c1] (3) -- (9);
\draw[c1] (7) -- (9);
\draw[c1] (8) -- (9);
\draw[c1] (0) -- (6);

\draw[c1] (1) -- (10);
\draw[c1] (6) -- (10);

\draw[c1] (1) -- (13);
\draw[c1] (6) -- (13);
\draw[c1] (8) -- (13);
\draw[c1] (10) -- (13);

\draw[c1] (7) -- (11);
\draw[c1] (13) -- (11);
\draw[c1] (9) -- (11);
\draw[c1] (8) -- (11);

\draw[c1] (11) -- (12);
\draw[c1] (9) -- (12);
\draw[c1] (7) -- (12);

\draw[c1] (5) -- (13);
\draw[c1] (0) -- (5);
\draw[c1] (5) -- (11);
\draw[c1] (3) -- (5);
\draw[c1] (3) -- (8);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: My miserable code]

I really don't know what I am doing so any advice is appreciated.
I later recompiled with Overleaf and I get the same issue:
[image: Overleaf problem]

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! It would be very helpful if you can include a compilable MWE, instead of a part of your code. Please check [I have just been asked to write an MWE. What is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)

Comment: Also, I have compiled the code and I do not understand where the problem is? For me there is no overlap in the resulting image.

Comment: @Jes thank you, I just attached the image of my graph.

Comment: Oh this does not happen to me. May I ask which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Jes MikTex. Only free one I could find haha

Comment: I use the same one! Maybe you have an old version of some package. I think you can check if there are uploada avaliable somewhere on the MixTeK console

Comment: @Jes Ok. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I tried to compile it with Overleaf (another free, online program) and it is working fine too

Comment: @Jes I just did too and I get the same problem, posting a picture of that as well

Comment: Ok that is weird. Maybe could you update your preamble on the code of your question?

Comment: How do you want this problem to be solved? Do you want the edged to be behind the nodes or do you want to shift the nodes, so that the edges do not cross them? Please advise ... The latter can be solved by adjusting the coordinates of the nodes, for the former, you should probably use the `backgrounds` library. Using a smaller font size could also solve this problem.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you, yes, the backgrounds solution was the one I wanted.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because soilved in the comments.